# Rails 3 - How to handle pagination according to time frame, not the number of posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

I would like to write a pagination functionality for my Rails 3 application that will break the posts in forum to pages. The division to pages is done **according to a time frame** (configurable by user), say 7 days, i.e. the first page shows posts from the last week, the second page shows the posts from the week before that, and so on.

Moreover, I would like to display some indication for users about the number of posts on each page. For example, I could set the `title` attribute of the link to the second page to "74 posts", or to change the background color according to the number of posts.

In other words, I need to know the number of posts on each page when rendering a page. Initially, I thought to store the number of posts on each page in a database, and update this number when a new message is added, or a message is deleted. But, since the time frame is configurable (it can be 7 days, 3 days, 1 month, or even 1 day), I'm not sure how to manage this is the database. Also, **I don't want to load all posts from the database** because the loading time will be very slow.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two params to your index action for date_from and date_to. Use these to select the records from the database and return them to the index.

See ActiveRecord [range conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#range-conditions) for more info.

As for counting the links in these ranges simply call count on them to return the number of items.